# 2D shift of an image changes its spectrum due to interpolation

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, interpolation, affinetransform

Consider the operation of 2D cyclic translation (i.e. shift) applied onto an image. In theory such operation should not change its spectrum (i.e. power of 2D Fourier representation) but it does if the image is not translated an integer number of pixels.

I believe this is due to the fact that an image is defined only on a finite grid and thus interpolation is used to calculate the values after translation; for example, translation of half-integer pixel zero-out the largest special frequency at the Fourier representation and other non-integer translations may have other "blurring" effects.
Using cubic rather than linear interpolation does not help here as for natural, slowly changing images both have a very similar results.

Is there a way to avoid this weird effect with integer vs non-integer translations?

I imagine two approaches here: either somewhat "blur" the original image so that integer translation would loose their grace or somehow force a translation which preserve the original spectrum.